# Convert point cloud raw data into Solid Edge or Solid Works 3D models

Tags: 3d, cad

We are looking for software that will convert point cloud raw data (from Faro scanners, for example) into a model that is compatible with Solid Edge or Solid Works, identifying planes (faces) etc.